# SOLR error exception issue

Tags: solr

We are getting the error below for our SOLR configuration. Any idea about this.

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for org.apache.solr.SolrSharp.Configuration.SolrSearchers threw an exception. ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Solr configuration error
at org.apache.solr.SolrSharp.Configuration.SolrSearchers..cctor()
```

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: can you post your config file for that core?

Comment: here is the web.config file entry <section name="solr" type="org.apache.solr.SolrSharp.Configuration.SolrConfigurationSection, SolrSharp" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />

Comment: No the one from the Solr server. It sounds like the XML config file for the core is malformed.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you didn't start (or didn't install) your Solr server.

1. Download latest version of [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)
2. Start the server by following the instructions in [Solr Tutorial](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_2_1/tutorial.html)
   The default port is 8983 so you should be able to reach your Solr server at localhost:8983/solr
3. In App.config file in SolrSharp, replace the port in the server's url

This should solve the problem.